# derivative of a function divided by the same function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've been trying to understand and look for a proof that for example

(1) $$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{f(x)}$$

is equal to

(2) $$\frac{d}{dx}ln[f(x)]$$

Can someone help me understand why 1 & 2 are equal?

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule? In this case $\displaystyle g(x)=\ln[f(x)]\implies \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}g(x)=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f(x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: It is easier in one variable calculus to use a ' instead of a d/dx to derive.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln f(x)]= \frac{1}{f(x)} \cdot f'(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{f(x)}$$
where the second step is true by the chain rule.